# physics of 2D car racing game with heightmap

Tags: 2d, physics, racing, car

I want to develop a simple car racing game where the road is defined by a heightmap. It looks basically like this:

[image: 2d car racing game]

The player can use throttle and brake to control the car.

I'm wondering what the best approach for the physics is. I have some ideas:

- Use a mass-spring system with one mass for each wheel.

  *Pro:* Gravity affects each wheel independly, so if one wheel stands on ground and the other one floats in the air, the car rotates. Can be extended to three dimensions by adding two more wheels.

  *Contra:* The distance between the weels varies. The system may explode (when forces amplify each other). The car will fall down if both wheels float, but the middle of the car touches ground.
- Define the car's state using position, momentum, rotation and spin.

  *Pro:* The wheel distance is constant, no springs included

  *Contra:* very complex, hard to compute, not really extensible to a third dimension

I think there must be a better way than those.

Comment: "Later, I want to add a third dimension" What?

Comment: I hope I can use the same technology (or at least the basic idea) in a three-dimensional race game later.

Comment: Ok, forget the thing about third dimension, it was only an idea... any constructive comment?

Comment: How did you come up with the _Pro_ and _Contra_ arguments? Using rigid body physics is actually easier and more stable than tweaking stiff springs for your car (and it won't be very pleasant). Undoubtedly, Box2D can do the hard work for you: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/04/06/two-ways-to-make-box2d-cars/ .

Comment: Thanks, @teodron! The second example was exactly what I was looking for. It uses springs, but I don't know if they are required.

Comment: To answer your question: I tried to use only one static body for the whole car instead of one for each wheel and axle, and so it was very hard to even calculate collision. I did not think of a composite body.

Comment: @Yogu: even with several constrained rigid bodies, the physics solver delivers much more believable results than stiff springs (these may either blow up at a certain point or necessitate breaking them off when the strain becomes too high and threatens the overall simulation stability). However, mass springs will get you there for your simple case too.. but they're not physically accurate. Collision handling is also quite difficult for MS systems since there's no easy way out of a colliding configuration. On the other hand, Box2D should deal perfectly with multiple rigids colliding at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply physics, you have to use physical engine.
I would recommend you to use [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) which is a good 2D physical engine for C++ or [JBox2D](http://www.jbox2d.org/) which is the Java version of Box2D. If you want a 3D physical engine I think Bullet is a nice one. There are lot of tutorials about all of them, just google it (I can't add more hyperlinks).